# How to compare file date modified using cakebuild?

Tags: cakebuild

Can not find related document in http://cakebuild.net/dsl/file-operations/

The cmake compares file date automatically, I'm wondering if there is similar facility in cakebuild?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no automatic file date comparing in Cake. It's just .NET so you can compare using `System.IO` just as in regular .NET.

```
var fileA = new System.IO.FileInfo("./filea.txt");
var fileB = new System.IO.FileInfo("./fileb.txt");

if (fileA.LastWriteTime > fileB.LastWriteTime)
{

}
```

or

```
var modifiedA = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("./filea.txt");
var modifiedB = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("./fileb.txt");

if (modifiedA > modifiedB)
{

}
```

If you want to check if two files are identical or not then there's built-in functionality to get the hash of a given file with the [CalculateFileHash](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Security/SecurityAliases/4070B6EE) alias.

```
var fileHashA = CalculateFileHash("filea.txt").ToHex();
var fileHashB = CalculateFileHash("fileb.txt").ToHex();

if (fileHashA != fileHashB)
{
    //DIFF
}
```